# I am unable to register user from my app using createUserWithEmailAndPassword in FirebaseAuth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Every time I try to create a user with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` it shows toast "Failed to Register" - which I have put to show if `task.isSuccessful` returns `false`. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong.

Here is my code:

```
progressDialog.setMessage("Registering please wait...");
            progressDialog.show();

            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                        {
                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                               Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"RegisteredSuccessfully!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Failed to Register. Please try again..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Comment: The email must be valid, and possibly the password must meet google's complexity requirements.  Are you sure both of these are true?

Comment: You need to first figure out what the problem/error is - for this you need to log or display the exception - do something like `Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed to Register. Please try again. Error is " +      
        task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla , I did what you said and I am getting error message in toast as- com.google.firebase.FirebaseException:An internal error occured.[OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED] ...please tell me now what to do.

Comment: Now, this is more like it. OK, did you enable Email/Password Authentication on your Firebase console? This has to be enabled. Please go to your [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and do that. Try again and let us know if you get the same error.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla , Yes!! It is already enabled...I enabled it at the starting of my project. But still I am getting such error. Is there anything else which I can try to remove such error?

Comment: @ user3137702, yes email and password both meets google's complexity requirements. Still am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had also suffered from this problem and i found the error was in because of google-service.json file so i downloaded latest google-service.json file from firebase and put in project level app and the error was gone.Try this.